# allowOutsideClick not working in SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, sweetalert2

```
function show_alert(args) {
    Swal.fire({
        icon: args.icon,
        title: args.title,
        text: args.message,
        html: args.html,
        allowEscapeKey: args.allowEscapeKey ? args.allowEscapeKey : true,
        allowOutsideClick: args.allowOutsideClick ? args.allowOutsideClick : true,
        confirmButtonText: args.confirmButtonText ? args.confirmButtonText : 'Tamam',
        confirmButtonColor: args.confirmButtonColor ? args.confirmButtonColor : '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonText: args.cancelButtonText ? args.cancelButtonText : 'İptal',
        cancelButtonColor: args.cancelButtonColor ? args.cancelButtonColor : '#d33',
        showCancelButton: args.showCancelButton === undefined ? false : args.showCancelButton,
        showCloseButton: args.showCloseButton === undefined ? false : args.showCloseButton,
        showConfirmButton: args.showConfirmButton === undefined ? true : args.showConfirmButton,
        didOpen: args.didOpen ? args.didOpen : null,
        reverseButtons: true,
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result['isConfirmed']) {
            args.callback ? args.callback_args ? args.callback(args.callback_args) : args.callback() : null;
        } else if (result['isDismissed'] && args['isDismissed']) {
            event.preventDefault();
            args.isDismissed ? args.isDismissed() : null;
        }
    });
}
```

The above code block is a general alert display function. I can display alerts based on the parameters I give in "args".

I wrote the following code blocks to show a loading alert when the user clicks a button:

```
show_alert({
    'title': 'Please wait',
    'html': 'Loading audio file ...',
    'allowEscapeKey': false,
    'allowOutsideClick': false,
    'showConfirmButton': false,
    'showCancelButton': false,
    'showCloseButton': false,
    'didOpen': () => {Swal.showLoading();},
    'isDismissed': () => {console.log('dismissed');}
});
```

However, when the user clicks anywhere on the page outside of the alert, the alert closes.

Is it possible to stop this by using a function like `event.preventDefault()`? If you can help, I would appreciate it.

In the "else if" block, I tried to catch the event and prevent the click event, like the "allowOutsideClick" property, but I couldn't.

Comment: `allowOutsideClick: args.allowOutsideClick ? args.allowOutsideClick : true,` is set on true inside your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ternary always sets `allowOutsideClick` to a truthy value:

```js
allowOutsideClick: args.allowOutsideClick ? args.allowOutsideClick : true
```

This needs to be changed to `false` if `allowOutsideClick` is falsy:

```
allowOutsideClick: args.allowOutsideClick ? args.allowOutsideClick : false
```

As SweetAlert accepts [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)/[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values for its options, this can be simplified to just:

```js
allowOutsideClick: args.allowOutsideClick
```

I would recommend looking at your other options and providing similar optimisations. Such as with the `allowEscapeKey` option (which seems to have a similar issue).

Also, anywhere that you have the pattern of:

```
a ? a : b
```

can be simplified to just

```js
a || b
```

As these mean the same thing.

```js
function show_alert(args) {
  Swal.fire({
    icon: args.icon,
    title: args.title,
    text: args.message,
    html: args.html,
    allowEscapeKey: args.allowEscapeKey,
    allowOutsideClick: args.allowOutsideClick,
    confirmButtonText: args.confirmButtonText || 'Tamam',
    confirmButtonColor: args.confirmButtonColor || '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonText: args.cancelButtonText || 'İptal',
    cancelButtonColor: args.cancelButtonColor || '#d33',
    showCancelButton: args.showCancelButton,
    showCloseButton: args.showCloseButton,
    showConfirmButton: args.showConfirmButton === undefined ? true : args.showConfirmButton,
    didOpen: args.didOpen,
    reverseButtons: true,
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result['isConfirmed']) {
      args.callback ? args.callback_args ? args.callback(args.callback_args) : args.callback() : null;
    } else if (result['isDismissed'] && args['isDismissed']) {
      event.preventDefault();
      args.isDismissed ? args.isDismissed() : null;
    }
  });
}

show_alert({
  'title': 'Please wait',
  'html': 'Loading audio file ...',
  'allowEscapeKey': false,
  'allowOutsideClick': false,
  'showConfirmButton': false,
  'showCancelButton': false,
  'showCloseButton': false,
  'didOpen': () => {
    Swal.showLoading();
  },
  'isDismissed': () => {
    console.log('dismissed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/11.6.16/sweetalert2.min.js" integrity="sha512-4aFcnPgoxsyUPgn8gNinplVIEoeBizjYPTpmOaUbC3VZQCsRnduAOch9v0Pn30yTeoWq1rIZByAE4/Gg79VPEA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/11.6.16/sweetalert2.css" integrity="sha512-JzSVRb7c802/njMbV97pjo1wuJAE/6v9CvthGTDxiaZij/TFpPQmQPTcdXyUVucsvLtJBT6YwRb5LhVxX3pQHQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
```

---

As a side note, you're misusing the conditional operator `? :` within your `.then()`. You should use these when you need to use the return value that the expression evaluates to. When you don't use the evaluated value, and instead just perform side-effects, such as calling a function, then you're better off using an if-statement.

I'd also argue that only calling `args.callback(args.callback_args)` only when `args.callback_args` is truthy probably isn't what youu want to do, as this prevents you from being able to specify `callback_args` as falsy values such as `false`, `0`, `""`, etc. You're better of always calling `args.callback(args.callback_args)`

Comment: I made the necessary corrections and it worked. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @BerkayÇavuşoğlu No worries, I added some further edits and code changes you might want to consider